# Hide specific elements in a page that have the same class or no classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

A client uses an external CRM platform to manage customers that I connected to his website using a dedicated plugin provided by this CRM company.

With this plugin I can display on the website informations that my client fill in this external platform.

I can't change the html code of this plugin (because is syncronized every 10 mins with the CRM platform) but I need to hide some of these informations coming from the CRM via Plugin.

In the specific this Plugin generates in the pages this kind of code

```
<div class="entry-content" itemprop="text">
    <h4 class='cx_h4'>Headline one</h4> 
    <p>Copy Text 1<br></p> 

    <h4 class='cx_h4'>Headline Two</h4> 
    <p>Copy Text 2<br></p> 

    <h4 class='cx_h4'>Headline Three</h4> 
    <p>Copy Text 3<br></p> 

    <h4 class='cx_h4'>Headline Four</h4> 
    <p>Copy Text 4<br></p> 

    <h4 class='cx_h4'>Headline Five</h4> 
    <p>Copy Text 5<br></p> 

    <h4 class='cx_h4'>Headline Six</h4> 
    <p>Copy Text 6<br></p> 
</div>
```

Has you can see every headline has class `cx_h4` and the copy-text instead is a simple paragraph.

The headlines with class `cx_h4` **never changes in the content**.

But the paragraph `p` always change.

My question is:

How can I hide for example **only** these informations?

```
<h4 class='cx_h4'>Headline Two</h4> 
    <p>Copy Text 2<br></p> 

<h4 class='cx_h4'>Headline Five</h4> 
    <p>Copy Text 5<br></p> 

<h4 class='cx_h4'>Headline Six</h4> 
    <p>Copy Text 6<br></p>
```

if I can't define classes or id for them?

Can I achieve this with CSS or jQuery? **Does this works cross-browsers?**

Do you have any tips? :)

Comment: What is the criteria to decide which elements to hide? All the headlines have same class!! The logic can be converted to code only if there is a logic. Do you want to hide the 2nd, 5th and 6th headlines every time?

Comment: Yes I need to hide them everytime. Those elements are "static" it means they never change position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the use of [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type):

```css
.entry-content h4:nth-of-type(2), /*Select second h4 element */
.entry-content p:nth-of-type(2), /*Select second p element */
.entry-content h4:nth-of-type(5),
.entry-content p:nth-of-type(5),
.entry-content h4:nth-of-type(6),
.entry-content p:nth-of-type(6){
 display:none
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content" itemprop="text">
    <h4 class='cx_h4'>Headline one</h4> 
    <p>Copy Text 1<br></p> 

    <h4 class='cx_h4'>Headline Two</h4> 
    <p>Copy Text 2<br></p> 

    <h4 class='cx_h4'>Headline Three</h4> 
    <p>Copy Text 3<br></p> 

    <h4 class='cx_h4'>Headline Four</h4> 
    <p>Copy Text 4<br></p> 

    <h4 class='cx_h4'>Headline Five</h4> 
    <p>Copy Text 5<br></p> 

    <h4 class='cx_h4'>Headline Six</h4> 
    <p>Copy Text 6<br></p> 
</div>
```

Comment: @Nuboja of course ;) check the link i shared at the bottom to see browser support

Answer (score -1):

With CSS

```
.cx_h4, .cx_h4~p{
  display: none;
}
```

With jQuery

```
$('.cx_h4, .cx_h4~p').hide();
```

Comment: This is not a solution because there are other elements with the same class .cx_h4.

I don't want to hide them all.

Comment: but based on which criteria do you want to hide them?

Comment: your question doesn't have enough information to find an answer.